# modifying a known map gmapping

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if it's possible to create a partial map using the navigation stack and then reloading the map later to complete it. Correct me if I am wrong but it seems you can load previously known maps to the amcl demo but that program does not build on the map, trying the same command to the gmapping demo doesnt seem to work:

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml
```

How does one complete a partial map? Also is it possible to edit the map.pgm file in something like gpaint to correct small errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37486/modifying-a-known-map-gmapping/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-28**:
yes you can do small corrections on the map. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29vGhoXGv_k check out this video it is an edited map and robot can do navigation

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-06-28**:
awesome, now I just need to figure out how to load in a partially completed map into the gmapping demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct that AMCL does not build maps, it only localizes within an existing map. GMapping does build maps while localizing (SLAM: Simultaneous Localization and Mapping).

There is currently no way to "resume mapping" when using gmapping. See http://answers.ros.org/question/9448/loading-a-prior-map-with-gmapping/#13721 for a detailed explanation. Basically, the map image and yaml file do not have enough information for GMapping to resume from.

It is definitely possible to edit the map.pgm file in an image editor like gimp (or I guess gpaint but I've never used it). You should make sure you preserve the image size and resolution (or adjust the map.yaml parameters accordingly). See http://answers.ros.org/question/12217/effects-of-manually-editing-gmapping-maps/#18030 for some more discussion on editing the map. Note that this will affect AMCL but you still cannot edit a map and then resume mapping (since, as noted above, gmapping can't resume from the .pgm/.yaml map).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-06-28**:
dang, thanks for the response

**Comment by [Dino](https://answers.ros.org/users/28388/dino/) on 2016-10-30**:
SO what are the missing parameters? I am interested in this as part of continuing mapping ( say, after docking for recharge). So the start orientation and location would be known. Why would it not be possible to continue after that?

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2021-05-12**:
Any updates on this matter?